# Hiding window in process.start() and moving this window

Tags: c#-4.0

I wrote this code, but I cannot hide and move the window.

How can I hide the window in Process.Start() and then move it and show it to the user?

```
[DllImport("USER32.dll")]
//[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

[DllImport("USER32.dll")]
private static extern bool UpdateWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\award_star_gold_2.png";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    Process processTemp = new Process();
    processTemp.StartInfo = startInfo;
    processTemp.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    processTemp.Start();

    processTemp.WaitForInputIdle();
    IntPtr id = processTemp.MainWindowHandle;
    Console.Write(id);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    MoveWindow(processTemp.MainWindowHandle, 10, 200, 200, 300, true);
    UpdateWindow(processTemp.MainWindowHandle);
}
```

Comment: Almost any sane GUI program, like the image viewer you are using, will ignore the request to hide its main window.  Because doing prevents the user from regaining control as well as ending the program, other than by using Task Manager.  Not having a usable main window handle is pretty normal as well, certainly on Windows 8 and up where the default image viewer is a WinRT app.  Get ahead by creating your own image viewer, you get full control over what it does.  The programmer's way.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind hiding the window in the first place? Alternatively can't you just parse the process output and show that to the user?

Comment: I use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) before MoveWindow. I see "award_star_gold_2.png" then this image moves. I do not want to see "award_star_gold_2.png" at first. I want to see "award_star_gold_2.png" after moving.

Comment: I used this code but the png does not move, why?   Process flash = new Process(); flash.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; flash.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\award_star_gold_2.png"; flash.Start(); IntPtr id = flash.MainWindowHandle; Console.Write(id); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); MoveWindow(flash.MainWindowHandle, 10, 10, 200, 300, true); UpdateWindow(flash.MainWindowHandle); ShowWindow(flash.MainWindowHandle, 1); https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx